# can't use Unicode characters using mysql command line

Tags: mysql, command-line

I found this weird behaviour using the mysql server 5.6 command line.

If I do:

```
source C:\Users\dyesdyes\Downloads\test.sql
```

and the code in this file is:

```
insert into `tWord`(`word`,`frequency`) values 
('à',16994.68);
```

The SQL to create the tWord table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tWord` (
  `idWord` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL,
  `frequency` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idWord`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idWord_UNIQUE` (`idWord` ASC),
  INDEX `word` (`word` ASC),
  INDEX `idWord` (`idWord` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 0
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

The error is:

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xE0' for column 'word'
>   at row 1

If I execute the same insert statement in the workbench client, it works fine. It only gives an error using the command line...

Any hint?

Comment: are you sure your .sql file is encoded using UTF8?

Comment: that's the issue! Make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

.sql file should be UTF8 encoded. Text editor should have a setting to save it that way.